# How to flash multiple HTML elements with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have some HTML that is copied X times. For this example lets say 3 times.

HTML:

```
<tr id="flashingtr" class="flashingtr">
    <td>name</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>16:00
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="flashingtr" class="flashingtr">
    <td>name</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>16:00
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="flashingtr" class="flashingtr">
    <td>name</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>16:00
    </td>
</tr>
```

And I have some Javascript running:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var flash = document.getElementById('flashingtr')
    setInterval(function () {
        flash.style.backgroundColor = (flash.style.backgroundColor == 'red' ? 'white' : 'red');
    }, 500);
</script>
```

Now this above Javascript works, but an Id can only exist once (in theorie). So I think that is why only the first `<tr>` is flashing.

So then I tried the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var flash = document.getElementsByClassName('flashingtr')
    setInterval(function () {
        flash.style.backgroundColor = (flash.style.backgroundColor == 'red' ? 'white' : 'red');
    }, 500);
</script>
```

But it does nothing.

**Question:
How can I flash multiple HTML elements with this code?**

Comment: Multiple same ids are disabled in HTML

Comment: That is not my question. I know this. The code is for example.

Comment: @NashCarp If you know this, it shouldn't surprise you that `getElementById` returns only one item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because `id` are unique. So `JavaScript` will only return one element.

In your case thats this element;

```
<tr id="flashingtr" class="flashingtr">
    <td>name</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>16:00
    </td>
</tr>
```

In your second example, you select the elements by class. This will return an `object` with a list of elements. You have to loop through the `objects`.

After reading your comments I came up with following.
You have to define the `for` loop inside the `setInterval`

This way it will work, and they will all flash.

```js
 var flash = document.querySelectorAll('.flashingtr');

setInterval(function () {   
  for(var i = 0;i < flash.length;i++) {
  var selector = flash[i];
        selector.style.backgroundColor = (selector.style.backgroundColor == 'red' ? 'white' : 'red');
  }
}, 500);
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="flashingtr">
      <td>name</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>16:00
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="flashingtr">
      <td>name</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>16:00
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="flashingtr">
      <td>name</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>16:00
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div class="test">
</div>
```

Comment: This code won't work, you got a typo `document.getElementByClassName('flashingtr')`

Comment: That's not the only typo. In the for loop, flash.style won't be defined. As flash is the array of elements.

Comment: Sorry, you guys right. I copied his code and pasted. Missed these typo's. Corrected it. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: I get what you're doing, I tried it but it still doesn't do anything.

Comment: I have selected this answer because of your `.querySelectorAll`. And because you're creating it outside of the `setInterval`. One little thing, I think it is better to use `flash[i]` then `selector`, because the code will be creating a variable for every interval and that requires some memory every 0,5 seconds. But maybe I am wrong about that.

Comment: How you select the elements doesn't really matter though. Just note that JavaScript doens't recongize `tr.flashingtr` selector if you didn't wrap an table arround it. Glad to hear I could help you.

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementByClassName` is not a function, you should use `document.getElementsByClassName`

Notice the 's' after Element : it returns an array.

Then you'll have to loop through your array of elements :

```
setInterval(function () {

    var flashElements = document.getElementsByClassName('flashingtr');
    var i;
    for (i=0;i<flashElements.length;i++) {
       flashElements[i].style.backgroundColor = (flashElements[i].style.backgroundColor == 'red' ? 'white' : 'red');
    }

}, 500);
```

**EDIT** : 
I moved the loop inside the setInterval function. That way, if a new TR with the 'flashingtr' class is added the document, it will be flashing too.

Comment: I tried your code and only the last one is flashing. The first two don't.

Comment: You're correct. I edited my answer and tested it. The three elements should be flashing now.

Comment: Thanks your answer works as well. I have selected the answer of @Red as the accepted answer because of the `querySelectorAll` he used. For example I can put `.flashingtr td:first-child` inside it. I liked that. 
And your `flashElements` could be set outside of the `setInterval` so it is only created once.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a CSS animation for the flashing effect?

```js
const
  selectElement = document.querySelector('#anim-select');

let
  oldStyle = '';
  
function onAnimStyleChanged(event) {
  const
    rows = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('tr'));
  if (oldStyle !== '') {
    rows.forEach(row => row.classList.remove(oldStyle));
  }
  
  oldStyle = event.target.value;
  if (oldStyle !== '') {
    rows.forEach(row => row.classList.add(oldStyle));
  }
  
}

selectElement.addEventListener('change', onAnimStyleChanged);
```

```css
@keyframes flashing-hard {
  0% { background-color: white; }
  49% { background-color: white; }
  50% { background-color: red; }
  100% { background-color: red; }
}

@keyframes flashing-soft {
  0% { background-color: white; }
  50% { background-color: red; }
}


table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.hard-flash > td {
  animation-duration: 1000ms;
  animation-name: flashing-hard;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

.soft-flash > td {
  animation-duration: 1000ms;
  animation-name: flashing-soft;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="flashingtr" class="">
        <td>name</td>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>16:00
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="flashingtr" class="">
        <td>name</td>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>16:00
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="flashingtr" class="">
        <td>name</td>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>16:00
        </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody> 
<table>

<label for="anim-select">Set animation style</label>
<select id="anim-select">
   <option value="">Off</option>
   <option value="soft-flash">Soft flash</option>
   <option value="hard-flash">Hard flash</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I like the soft flashing but I don't need a very beautiful flash. So because I don't need that I don't like the many lines of code. At this moment I can do the same with a lot less lines. But thanks for the idea! Maybe someone else reading this needs it.